# Implement fibonacci using recursion without using java.bignumber

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to implement the Fibonacci sequence without using the BigInteger Class import, hence I rewrite my own add method, and I spent two days on it, But I don't know why the answer of the first 6 numbers is correct and the rest of the answers are the reverse of the correct one(eg. n = 7, my answer: 31 the correct one: 13; n = 15, my answer = 016, correct one= 610), and when n becomes greater, the answer gets totally wrong(not even the reversed of the correct one. This happened when n >= 25).
Any advice would be appreciated!

The following is my output:

```
  The 0th Fibonacci number is :
    0
    The 1th Fibonacci number is :
    1
    The 2th Fibonacci number is :
    1
    The 3th Fibonacci number is :
    2
    The 4th Fibonacci number is :
    3
    The 5th Fibonacci number is :
    5
    The 6th Fibonacci number is :
    8
    The 7th Fibonacci number is :
    31
    The 8th Fibonacci number is :
    12
    The 9th Fibonacci number is :
    43
    The 10th Fibonacci number is :
    55
    The 11th Fibonacci number is :
    98
    The 12th Fibonacci number is :
    441
    The 13th Fibonacci number is :
    332
    The 14th Fibonacci number is :
    773
    The 15th Fibonacci number is :
    016
    The 16th Fibonacci number is :
    789
    The 17th Fibonacci number is :
    7951
    The 18th Fibonacci number is :
    4852
    The 19th Fibonacci number is :
    1814
    The 20th Fibonacci number is :
    5676
    The 21th Fibonacci number is :
    64901
    The 22th Fibonacci number is :
    11771
    The 23th Fibonacci number is :
    75682
    The 24th Fibonacci number is :
    86364
    The 25th Fibonacci number is :
    52047
    The 26th Fibonacci number is :
    393021
    The 27th Fibonacci number is :
    814491
    The 28th Fibonacci number is :
    118413
    The 29th Fibonacci number is :
    922905
    The 30th Fibonacci number is :
    040428
```

And the following is my code:

```
package com.example.helloworld;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Fibonacci_Recursive{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        long time = 0L;
        for(int i = 0; time <= 60L; i++)
        {
            Fibonacci_Recursive fr = new Fibonacci_Recursive(i);
            time = ((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000_000_000);
        }
    }

    private Fibonacci_Recursive(int n){
        System.out.println("The " + n + "th Fibonacci number is :");
        if (n <= 1){
            System.out.println(n);
        }
        else {
            int[] finalResult = getF(n);
            String st = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < finalResult.length; i++){
                st = finalResult[i] + st;
            }
            System.out.println(st);
        }
    }

    private int[] getF(int n){
        int[] head = new int[1];
        if (n <= 1) {
            head[0] = n;
            return head;
        }
        return add(getF(n - 1), getF(n - 2));
    }

    private int[] add(int[] s1, int[] s2){
        int carrier = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] array1 = s1;
        int[] array2 = s2;
        array1 = reverseGeneralArray(array1);
        array2 = reverseGeneralArray(array2);
        int min = array2.length;
        int min2 = array1.length;

        if(min2 > min) {
            for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
                int x = array1[i] + array2[i];
                result.add((x + carrier) % 10);
                carrier = x / 10;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= min2 - min - 1; j++) {
                int index = min;
                result.add((array1[index] + carrier) % 10);
                carrier = (array1[index] + carrier) / 10;
                index++;
            }
            if (carrier > 0) {
                result.add(carrier);
            }
            Collections.reverse(result);
            return convertIntegers(result);
        }
        else if(min2 < min)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < min2; i ++){
                    int x = array1[i] + array2[i];
                    result.add((x + carrier) % 10);
                    carrier = x / 10;
                }
                for(int j = 0; j <= min - min2 - 1; j++){
                    int index = min2;
                    result.add((array2[index] + carrier) % 10);
                    carrier = (array2[index] + carrier) / 10;
                    index++;
                }
                if (carrier > 0) {
                    result.add(carrier);
                }
                Collections.reverse(result);
                return convertIntegers(result);
            }else {
                for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
                    int x = array1[i] + array2[i];
                    result.add((x + carrier) % 10);
                    carrier = x / 10;
                }
                if (carrier > 0) {
                    result.add(carrier);
                }
            Collections.reverse(result);
            return convertIntegers(result);
            }

    }

    private static int[] convertIntegers(ArrayList<Integer> integers)
    {
        int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < integers.size(); i++)
        {
            ret[i] = integers.get(i);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private int[] reverseGeneralArray(int[] x){
        int[] newX = new int[x.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            newX[i] = x[x.length - i -1];
        }
        return newX;
    }

}
```

Comment: What BigNumber class? There is no such class in the JDK. Do you mean BigInteger? Also, why not use it?

Comment: A `BigInteger` works by first using one `int` for the data. If that `int` overflows and can not hold the data anymore, a second `int` is introduced and so on. Very straightforward and you can not implement this in a better way in general. So your own idea will probably be the same in the end.

Comment: I am sorry, i mean bigInteger..

Comment: I know that i will eventually implemented like BigInteger , but i just need to implement the add method here. and i just cannot figure out what is wrong with my code...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @JoeC Really thank you!!!! That was really helpful link. i will spent time learning it.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss building the result, you concatenate wrong (reverse) way `String st` from the `int[] finalResult`:

```
private Fibonacci_Recursive(int n) {
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < finalResult.length; i++) {
        //Replaced st = finalResult[i] + st by
        st = st + finalResult[i];
    }
    ...
}
```

**Extra**: Consider, when concatenating strings in a loop, since concatenation copies the whole string, to use `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < finalResult.length; i++) {
    st.append(finalResult[i]);
}
```

**Update:** Starting from 25, an error becomes evident: the carrier is not right when the sum of two digits is equal to 10 (74025 instead of 75025). The bug is at the `add` method,where the carrier should be calculated as:

```
carrier = (x + carrier) / 10;
```

i.e.: you have to take into account previous carrier.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!! i will never find that without your help..... and i really appreciated your extra advice, i will use String builder in the future. However, i still couldn't find the reason why i get wrong answer after n >= 25. Do you have any clues?

Comment: You are welcome. Please, check the updated answer to find the reason of the error after n>=25.

Comment: That is the point!!! How can you find so quickly... Do you debug or use somthing else???

Comment: A debugger is a powerful tool for finding errors, you definitely have to learn. Taking a close look at when the results start to diverge (74025 instead of 75025) it seemed like it was related to the carrier.

Comment: @Richard, please, dont forguet to mark the answer for your question.